# Change background in slicknav when open/closed

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, menu, slicknav

I'm trying to change the background in Slicknav for when the Slicknav menu is opened and closed.

i use this code, but it doesnt work to me.

```
$(function(){
  var $bg;
    $('#menu-home').slicknav({
    duplicate: false,
    label: '',
    init: function(){
         $bg = $(".slicknav_menu");
    },
    open: function(){
         $bg.css({'background': '#222 !important'});
    },
    close: function(){
         $bg.css({'background': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'});
    }
    });
});
```

I've tried using basic if this then that and I feel like I'm just messing up this very simple piece of javascript.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you're using the latest version of SlickNav, but as of v1.0.3 the proper callbacks are `beforeOpen`, `afterOpen`, `beforeClose` and `afterClose`.

Here's a quick pen with background change working as expected:
http://codepen.io/ComputerWolf/pen/KpEKMW

As a note, these are fired when the menu is opened and closed as well as each submenu. You can use the `trigger` to check what is firing the callback if you only want to change the background when the entire menu is opened or closed.

Answer (score 0):

To expound on @ComputerWolf I added the following to add and remove a class that I styled in Css.  I used the trigger to check if it came from the Open/Close Button rather than a SubMenu

```
$('#mobile-menu').slicknav({
      label: '',
      beforeOpen: function(trigger){
        if($(trigger).hasClass('slicknav_btn')){ 
            $('.slicknav_menu').addClass('open-menu');
        }
      },
      afterClose: function(trigger){
        if($(trigger).hasClass('slicknav_btn')){ 
            $('.slicknav_menu').removeClass('open-menu');
        }
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
/* slicknav mobile menu active 
      ========================================================*/
    var $bg;
    $('.mobile-menu').slicknav({
      prependTo: '.navbar-header',
      parentTag: 'liner',
      allowParentLinks: true,
      duplicate: true,
      label: '',
      closedSymbol: '<i class="lni-chevron-right"></i>',
      openedSymbol: '<i class="lni-chevron-down"></i>',
      init: function () {
        $bg = $('.slicknav_menu');
      },
      afterOpen: function () {
        $bg.css({ 'background': 'rgba(25,118,210,.95)' });
      },
      afterClose: function () {
        $bg.css({ 'background': 'transparent' });
      }
    });
```